# Media folders missing from admin in 2.4.3-p3 update

Tags: media-images, magento2.4.3.p1

There are multiple media folders missing in 2.4.3-p3

I have read this --> https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/modify-image-library-permissions/

Does anyone know exactly where to add/edit this file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or update a config.xml file in a custom module at `\Vendor\Module\etc\config.xml`, per the instructions in your link:

> In this tutorial, you will learn how to extend "Media Gallery Allowed"
> folders using the config.xml file.
>
> Create a config.xml file.
>
> 1. If your module does not have one, create a config.xml file under the
>    etc directory.

Then simply copy and paste the example Magento suggests into your config.xml file.

[This link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/magento-2-developers/9781785886584/ch12s03.html) demonstrates a very streamlined example of what a config.xml might look like, and includes the xsd configuration, which is nice, since you'll need that as well and Magento doesn't include it in their example.

If you're quite new to Magento and haven't created your own module yet, [start with Magento's docs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-learn/tutorials/backend-development/create-module.html).

Comment: so I'm a little lost here sorry. I'm a bit of a noob tbh. So the config.xml should be located here? Is this correct? /public_html/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery/etc/config.xml And if so this code should specify the directory, and I need to add the code over for each directory I want to use? ```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd"> <default> <system> <media_storage_configuration> <allowed_resources> <media_gallery_image_folders> <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders --> <my_image_fo

Comment: Close. You don't want to add files to modules in the vendor directory, though. What you want to do instead is use (or create) a custom module under the app/code directory. In my first sentence, the example "\Vendor\Module\etc\config.xml" would be located at /public_html/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml. The app/code directory is where you should create your own modules for custom work like this.