# Magetno 2.4.3-p3 no folders show up in wysiwig interface - where to put new config.xml

Tags: magento2.4, cms, media, gallery

No folders show up in wysiwig interface in 2.4.3-p3

I have read this --> https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/modify-image-library-permissions/
and this --> [Media folders missing from admin in 2.4.3-p3 update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360180/media-folders-missing-from-admin-in-2-4-3-p3-update/)

Does anyone know exactly where to add the new config.xml file to be able to see the images and folders in the CMS media library tool?

Inside my directory at /public_html/app/code there are 2 directorys. Mageplaza and Smartwave.

```
/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza
/public_html/app/code/Smartwave
```

Where should I put the new config.xml? Do I have to create a new directory or put it in an existing one?

If I'm adding a configuration for the media viewer in the CMS would I have to create a directory path that emulates one from another location?

I'm completely confused here. Can some please tell me the exact path? Like, pretend I don't know anything about Magento! lol

Also, do I need to use this code over and over for each new directory inside the wysiwig directory or does it cover all the new directories I create?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
   <default>   
      <system>
         <media_storage_configuration>
            <allowed_resources>
               <media_gallery_image_folders>
                  <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders -->
                  <my_image_folder>wysiwyg</my_image_folder>
                  <my_catalog_image_folder>media/wysiwyg</my_catalog_image_folder>
               </media_gallery_image_folders>
            </allowed_resources>
         </media_storage_configuration>
      </system>
   </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

`app/code/Mageplaza` and `app/code/Smartwave` are vendor directories for third-party extensions.
You should create a new custom module within your vendor directory. You can use your company, project, or even your name as the vendor name.

In this post, I'll use **Magetu** as the vendor name.
Since this configuration (media library folder permissions) is related to the `Magento_Cms` module, I'll set the name of my custom module as **Cms**.

Here are the steps to create the custom module and deploy the changes:

Step 1: Create the `registration.php`:
File path: `app/code/Magetu/Cms/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Magetu_Cms', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create the `module.xml`:
File path: `app/code/Magetu/Cms/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magetu_Cms">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the `config`.xml file:
File path: `app/code/Magetu/Catalog/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <media_gallery_image_folders>
                        <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders -->
                        <mageplaza_image_folder>mageplaza</mageplaza_image_folder>
                        <your_image_folder>your_image_folder</your_image_folder>
                    </media_gallery_image_folders>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```

Step 4: Deploy the changes:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you are in the [**production**](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/set-mode.html?lang=en#:%7E:text=be%20var.-,Display%20the%20current%20mode,-The%20easiest%20way) mode, you'll need to deploy static content.

---

- If you want to allow any directories within the `wysiwyg` directory, declare them in the `config.xml` file.
- If multiple modules contain images within `wysiwyg` directory, you can add them all within a single module.
- If you want to allow a specific image directory for a specific module, you can use the config in its respective module. For example, if the module is `Magetu_Catalog`, the config file path should be: `app/code/Magetu/Catalog/etc/config.xml`.